# Find all parameters $\alpha$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x(x^2/2 + 1)^{\alpha}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

> Find all parameters $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty} x(x^2/2 + 1)^{\alpha}$ converges.

Can you help me with it? I have no idea how to start. I know some techniques, but I still have a problem.

Comment: Did you notice that $x\,dx=(\frac{x^2}2)'$ ?

Comment: And, better $x\,dx=(\frac{x^2}2+1)'$. So, start changing variable to make the problem quite simple.

Comment: By $1+x^2/2=u$ you have $xdx=du$. Write: $\int_{0}^{\infty}u^\alpha=\int_{0}^{\epsilon}u^\alpha+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}u^\alpha=I+J$. Then, it easy to check that for what values $\alpha$ the integrals $I$ and $J$ converge.

Comment: @Albert note that $u\ge1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $x^2/2 + 1 = y$ so $\text{d}y = x\text{d}x$ and your integral becomes

$$\int_1^{+\infty} y^{\alpha}\ \text{d}y$$

From this you see immediately that the integral converges iff $\alpha < -1$

Comment: This is clear! (+1)

Comment: @OlivierOloa Thank you!!

Comment: Why you get $\int_1^{\infty}$ instead of $\int_0^{\infty} $ ?

Comment: @Happyman Because when you make a substitution, you have to set the extrema with respect to the substitution you make. When $x = 0$, you have $y = 0/2 + 1 = 1$ hence the first extrema is $1$.

Answer (score 3):

$\int\limits_0^n x (\frac{x^2}{2}+1)^\alpha dx=\frac{(\frac{n^2}{2}+1)^{\alpha +1}-1}{\alpha +1}$ for $\alpha \ne -1$

$\alpha =-1$: $\,\,\int\limits_0^n x (\frac{x^2}{2}+1)^{-1}dx=\ln(\frac{n^2}{2}+1)$

$n\to\infty$: $\,\,$For $n^{2(\alpha +1)}<\infty$ it's necessary that $\alpha \lt -1$.

Comment: A clear answer! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha\ge 0$ then, as $M \to \infty$,
$$
\int_{0}^M x(x^2/2 + 1)^{\alpha}dx \ge \int_{0}^Mx\:dx \to \infty
$$ the initial integral is divergent.

Let's assume $\alpha<0$, a potential issue is only near $x \to \infty$.

As $x \to \infty$,
$$
 x(x^2/2 + 1)^{\alpha} \sim \frac{x}{(x^2/2)^{-\alpha}}=\frac1{2^\alpha \cdot x^{-2\alpha-1}}
$$ the latter integrand is convergent near $x \to \infty$ *iff* $-2\alpha-1>1$ that is $\alpha<-1$.

> Thus the initial integral is convergent *iff* $\alpha<-1$.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, couldn't we conclude faster changing variable first and just consider the problem of $\int_0^M u^\alpha\, du$ ? For sure, your solution is very good. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You are right! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x^{2}/2$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x \left(\frac{x^{2}}{2}+1\right)^{a} \mathrm{d}x
= \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} (y+1)^{a} \mathrm{d}y
= \mathrm{B}(1,-a-1)$$
By the [definition of the beta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12#E3), we have $Re(-a-1) \gt 0\,$ and thus $a \lt -1$.